# A problem about operators on an Euclidean space

Tags: linear-algebra, adjoint-operators, orthogonal-matrices, self-adjoint-operators, normal-operator

> Let $A, B$ be self-adjoint positive operators, $C, D$ be orthogonal
>   operators on an Euclidean space, and $AC = DB$.
>
> Prove that $C=D$.

I know many properties of self-adjoint and orthogonal operators and tried to apply them but with no success. Could you please help me?

> UPD: From $AC = DB$, since $C$ is orthogonal, we have $A=DBC^*$. Hence, $A^*=CB^*D^*$, and since $A$ and $B$ are self-adjoint, $A=CBD^*$. Multiplying these two decompositions of $A$ we get $A^2=DB^2D^*=CB^2C^*$.

Can we now say that $C=D$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose that by "positive operators", you mean *strictly* positive (i.e. positive definite) linear operators. Otherwise the statement is false, such as when $A=B=\operatorname{diag}(1,0),C=I$ and $D= \operatorname{diag}(1,-1)$.

Since $A^2=(AC)(AC)^T=(DB)(DB)^T=DB^2D^T$ and positive operators have unique positive square roots, we have $A=DBD^T$ and hence $AD=DB$. Thus $AC\,(=DB)=AD$ and in turn, $C=D$.

Comment: I got it (slightly differently) but I do not know how exactly to get the answer from this.

Comment: How do you obtain $C = D$ from $AC = AD$? I think this is not true in general.

Comment: @Jan $A$ is positive definite. Hence nonsingular.

Comment: Ok, the problem is that in my mind a positive operator $A$ is one which fulfills $\langle Ax, x \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$, which in general does not imply that $A$ is invertible.

Comment: @Jan Then the problem statement is false, as the counterexample in the first paragraph shows.

Comment: Ah, I see, thanks! I looked so long for a counterexample. Really good answer.